# EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE No MediaQuery widget found. MyHomePage widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to add a BottomModelSheet to add new transcations in the transaction list, i follow the and this is the error i am getting, what am i missing here ?

this is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:expense_tracker/widgets/transaction_list.dart';

import './widgets/transaction_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './widgets/new_transaction.dart';
import './models/transaction.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyHomePage());

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // String titleInput;
  // String amountInput;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final titleController = TextEditingController();

  final amountController = TextEditingController();

  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: 't1',
      title: 'New Shoes',
      amount: 1000,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      id: 't2',
      title: 'USB Cable',
      amount: 600,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  void _addNewTransaction(String txTitle, double txAmount) {
    final newTX = Transaction(
        title: txTitle,
        amount: txAmount,
        date: DateTime.now(),
        id: DateTime.now().toString());

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTX);
    });
  }

  void _startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(context: ctx,builder: (bCtx) {
      return NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter App'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text('CHART'),
                    elevation: 10,
                  ),
                ),
                TransactionList(_userTransactions),
              ]),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the same BottomModalSheet will be shown while clicking the icon on the appBar and the floatingActionButton in the bottom, they both dont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BuildContext` that you're passing to the `_startAddNewTransaction` method is that of the `_MyHomePageState`. Since `_MyHomePageState` contains the `MaterialApp` (and not the other way round), its `BuildContext` doesn't know about it.

You have 2 options:

1. Wrap the widgets that call that method with a `Builder` widget, whose `BuildContext` will know about the `MaterialApp`
2. Create a new widget (e.g. `MyHomePageContent`) and pass it to the `body:` parameter of the material app.

The first option is a quick fix, the second options is the better one.

---

It would be a good idea to separate your project into multiple files, like so:

*main.dart*

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

*my_app.dart*

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
      );
    }
}
```

*my_home_page.dart*

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // String titleInput;
  // String amountInput;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final titleController = TextEditingController();

  final amountController = TextEditingController();

  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: 't1',
      title: 'New Shoes',
      amount: 1000,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      id: 't2',
      title: 'USB Cable',
      amount: 600,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  void _addNewTransaction(String txTitle, double txAmount) {
    final newTX = Transaction(
        title: txTitle,
        amount: txAmount,
        date: DateTime.now(),
        id: DateTime.now().toString());

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTX);
    });
  }

  void _startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: ctx,
        builder: (bCtx) {
          return NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('CHART'),
                  elevation: 10,
                ),
              ),
              TransactionList(_userTransactions),
            ]),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```